# Django ORM: Min('field',filter=...) causes TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-orm

There is a model `Location` which can have many `Ticket` objects (using `ForeignKey`).

The `Ticket` model has `price` field which is a `DecimalField`.

Now I have FILTERED QuerySet of `Ticket` objects and I want to get QuerySet of `Location` objects and annotate `min_price` value which is a min price for all `Ticket` objects from the FILTERED QuerySet.

For example:

```
tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(something)

locations = Location.objects.all().annotate(min_price=<minimal price from tickets having this location>)
```

What I tried:

```
locations_annotated = Location.objects.all().annotate(
            min_price=Min('tickets__min_price', filter=tickets))
```

This doesn't work. When I try to get a first element from `locations_annotated`, debugger returns:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

Do you know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should pass `django.db.models.query_utls.Q` object as `filter` param instead of filtered queryset into `Min`:

```
locations_annotated = Location.objects.all().annotate(
            min_price=Min('ticket__price', filter=Q(something)))
```

Note that all filters within `something` should be prepended with `ticket__` prefix

Answer (score 0):

I think annotate is not used properly. Please try,

```
locations_annotated = Location.objects.annotate(
        min_price=Min('tickets__min_price', filter=tickets)
```